# KVM switch screen resolution problems

Tags: screen, resolution, kvm

Problem description: One laptop connected to a monitor via a KVM switch has correct screen resolution while other laptop with exact same configuration connected to the same KVM switch has very low resolution. I have tried switching ports/cables/restarting/various combinations of connecting and disconnecting the screen from KVM switch but same problem persists consistently.

I have a Dell SX2210b monitor. I bought a KVM switch from ebay:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/330559460038?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Both my office laptops are Dell and have Windows 7. Here is the configuration details:

Good laptop(Dell E5440):

```
  System:
     Windows 7 Enterprise with Service Pack 1
     Processor: Intel Core i5-4310U
     System type: 64 bit
  Monitor:
     Detected as Generic Non-PnP Monitor
     Driver provider: Microsoft
     Driver date: 6/21/2006
     Driver version: 6.1.7600.16385
  Display adapter:
     Detected as Intel HD Graphics Family
     Driver provider: Intel
     Driver date: 3/30/2014
     Driver version: 10.18.10.3540
```

Bad laptop (Dell E5440):

```
  System: Same as good laptop
  Monitor: Same as good laptop
  Display adapter: Everything is same except driver date is 4/24/2014 and 
                   driver version is: 10.18.10.3574
```

On the bad laptop I ran update driver to see if that resolves the issue but it didnt. This is when the driver got upgraded and that is the only difference.

Configurations being the same, Good laptop shows resolution of upto 1920x1080 but the bad laptop shows resolution limited to 1280x1024 and the screen flickers and shakes. Any ideas what am I doing wrong on the bad laptop?

Cheers
Omi

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the KVM Switch you have only support EDID channel communication to the connected display monitor with one port not bot of them.

If you swap your systems connection to the KVM switch, if the issue not follow the systems but follow the port of the connections to the KVM, then that proof my guesting is correct.

Then you should find KVM switch supporting Full time DDC/EDID video emulation to solve this issue fully.

Comment: I have tried switching the ports, the problem stays with the system.